# Show specific page templates for several woo-commerce product categories

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with a woo-commerce plugin based website which needs to be customized for showing specific page templates for the main top 5 categories.

How can templates be shown based on product category id or anything more convenient to achieve this objective?

For example: `Men` and `Women` are product categories while `AXX` and `BXX` are custom templates. If `Men` product category is opened it should show content from template `AXX` and same for another category.

Any help will be appreciated.